# PowerShell Array: select a value from array using gci

Tags: powershell-2.0

I have a directory on a share were the prefix of each file name has to be moved to a specific directory.  The -filter commands works to move the files but it would be nice to use the value of an array instead.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$source ="\\127.0.0.1\share\"

$File_Array_8HP70=@("108701")
$File_Array_8HP70X=@("108702")
$File_Array_9HP48=@("109401", "1094080", "1094090")
$File_Array_9HP48X=@("109402", "1094091", "1094082", "1094092")

$destination="\\127.0.0.1\TestFolder1\$DTS"
         $destination1="\\127.0.0.1\TestFolder2\$DTS"
         $destination2="\\127.0.0.1\TestFolde3\$DTS"

         $destination_array=@("$destination", "$destination1", "$destination2")

# filter works below - need to use array


         #$files = get-childitem $source -filter "108701*" -recurse
         #foreach ($file in $files)
         #{move-item $file.fullname $destination_array[0] -force}

         $files = gci $source |select-object -equals $file_array_8HP70
         foreach ($file in $files)
         {move-item $file.name is $($file_array_8hp70.name) $destination_array[0] -force}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you write :

```
$source ="\\127.0.0.1\share\*"
$File_Array_8HP70_start = $File_Array_8HP70 | % {$_+"*"}
$files = get-childitem $source -include $File_Array_8HP70_start -recurse
```

It should help.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help!  If you have some extra time could you please explain % {$_+"*"}

Comment: % is the alias of foreach-object Cmdlet. I use it to add create a new array with a '*' at the end of the string. -include param of Get-Chilitem take an array, this is not the case of -filter.

Comment: My script is working properly with the current array values; however, the actual file names will have about five characters in the prefix that I would like ignored: Example of one of the file names: 03_R___1087010076_9999992_35_401_01_20121107_134029_0667.I00.asd . The only part of the file name that I would like to parse is "108701####" ignoring the prefix 03_R___.

Comment: Found what I was looking for:  added *108701* on the first array value.